# html print page , extra blank page printed

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an HTML page, when Ι do print preview or print the document out, extra page is always printed.

Below is my CSS for printing the page out. Τried solution from other mentions in StackOverflow, all didn't help

```
@media print {
    @page { 
        margin-top: 17mm; 
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom:25mm;
    }

    body { 
        margin: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
        page-break-after: avoid;
}

    .container {
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your margin. My guess is that you have the page to 100% and then made it bigger by adding margins making the computer think it needs to print out two pages.